# Changing sort order for presentation by Jetpack infinite scroll

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, sql, plugin-jetpack, infinite-scroll

I have been able to use WordPress filters for `posts_join_paged`, `posts_where`, and `posts_orderby` to create a query that presents a set of artists where only artists who have a last name listed in the `custom-last-name` post metadata appear listed by that last name. This works when used as a regular page with manual paging.  However, it does not work with Jetpack's infinite scroll enabled.

Here are some of the details in the scenario. This is an archive page for the custom post type "artist". In `functions.php` I have the following:

```
add_filter('posts_join_paged','my_posts_join_paged');
add_filter('posts_where','my_posts_where');
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'my_posts_orderby');

function my_posts_join_paged($join_statement) {
    global $wp_query;
    global $wpdb;

    if ($wp_query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'artist') {
           $join_statement .= "INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS meta ON $wpdb->posts.ID = meta.post_id";
    }
    return $join_statement;
}

function my_posts_where($where_statement) {
    global $wp_query;
    global $wpdb;

    if ($wp_query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'artist') {
           $where_statement .= "AND meta.meta_key = 'custom-last-name'";
    }
    return $where_statement;
}

function my_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {
    global $wp_query;
    global $wpdb;

    if ($wp_query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'artist') {
           $orderby_statement = "meta.meta_value ASC, $wpdb->posts.post_title ASC";
    }
    return $orderby_statement;
}
```

With Jetpack's infinite scroll turned on the first page is sorted properly, but then subsequent pages do not appear in last name order. It also appears that some artist posts get skipped entirely.

Any ideas how to introduce this kind of custom sort limited only to posts of a certain type in such a way that it will work with Jetpack's infinite scroll?

There is a Jetpack filter called `infinite_scroll_query_args` which might be helpful, but it seems that at the time it is called there is nothing that can be used to detect whether or not to make the `orderby` change. Note that on other infinite scroll pages on the site I want to let default ordering prevail.